# Setting up a server with IPv6

Tags: networking, server, 15.10, ip, ipv6

I have just upgraded my internet and my ISP (Comcast) sent me a new modem/router in one. I have managed to set the static IP of the server but after searching all over I can't figure out how to do the IPv6 part.  I have never had IPv6 before, I managed to find my normal IP thanks to speedtest.net because all any other site would give me is the IPv6 version, but when browsing to my IP (either normal or IPv6) I cant get it to load.  All the required ports are open through the router, and I'm just lost.

I know this may be a little broad but I really need some help.

This is my [ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8jWt.png)

```
enp0s7    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:97:ae:b3:e2
      inet addr:10.0.0.50  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2601:403:c101:5ee0:221:97ff:feae:b3e2/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::221:97ff:feae:b3e2/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:23870 (23.8 KB)  TX bytes:12041 (12.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and this is how I currently have [/etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyubM.png)

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s7
iface enp0s7 inet static
address 10.0.0.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Currently these are the ports I have open and using open check they are visable. (top link is a screenshot for better reference)

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6iJ9.png

HTTP    TCP/UDP 80      80      10.0.0.50   -       
SSH     TCP/UDP 2222    2222    10.0.0.50   -   
XRDP    TCP/UDP 3389    3389    10.0.0.50   -
```

I have nothing in the "Server IPv6" part because I don't know what exactly I need there...

How can I get this all working with IPv6? what IP (normal or v6) would I enter into my domains DNS?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: added the text =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 is designed to autoconfigure in many cases.  The command `ip -6 show addr` will show any configured IPv6 addreses.  Addresses starting with `fe80::` are link local addresses and won't be routed to the internet.  The address(es) you are interested in will end with `/128`.  The addresses ending `/64` are networks you are connected to.

To test connectivity try a command like `ping6 google.com`.  Browsing to `http://test-ipv6.com/` will provide addition information on your connectivity.

You may want to read [the Linux IPv6 HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/).  I started with [6to4 tunneling](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-6to4-on-openwrt/) and progressed to [6in4 tunneling](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-ipv6-part-2/) documenting some of the changes I did.

You will want to firewall some but not all ICMPv6 types, as well as enabling DNS, HTTP, HTTPS, and other services.  It is difficult to hand wire the IPTables rules so I use [Shorewall6](http://shorewall.net/IPv6Support.html) to build my rules.  It is available as an Ubuntu package.  It takes a small amount of effort to do the initial setup, but the documentation is good.

From your listing, it does not appear you need to update `/etc/network/interfaces`.  If you have/want a static IPv6 addres, then add a stanza like the following:

```
iface enp0s7 inet6 static
    address xxxx::...
    gateway xxxx::...
```

If Comcast are routing the whole `/64` your way, you can pick any static IP you want.  You could also announce that `/64` to your LAN if your have one.  However, you should have been given a separate `/64`, `/56`, or `/48` for that purpose.  A `RADV` daemon is usually used to do the announcement, and it can be configured for dynamically allocated IPv6 addresses.